# Dropbox's built-in notification system

Tags: cocoa, macos, user-interface, dropbox

Does anyone know how to create a notify window like the dropbox's built-in notification system in cocoa?

[window like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3agN.jpg)

Links about the [notification system](http://www.dropbox.com/help/48)

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it just Growl, or am I missing something ? Is there some reason why you can't just use Growl ? http://growl.info/

Comment: I just want to write a soft which have a notify window,but not all of the people had installed the growl , so built-in is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your question: Dropbox is using Growl for notifications. Here is [Growl developer documentation](http://growl.info/documentation/developer/implementing-growl.php). Oh, and don't tell the Growl developers that the nofitication system is [built-in](http://growl.info/thirdpartyinstallations.php). ;-)

Comment: Not the Growl,as Dropbox says "If you don't have Growl installed when you install Dropbox on your Mac, don't worry. You'll still get notifications using Dropbox's built-in notification system."

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the way to implementation this.
Do not use the Interface Builder,objective-c code instead.Rewrite the NSWindow as you want.